# A term for "accommodating for others' language mistakes"

Tags: terminology

Is there a specific term for a phenomenon or an ability to accommodate for others' mistakes either in speech or in writing?

Something that a native or experienced speaker performs unconsciously or a skill they naturally possess. And something that a learner of a language lacks, which forces them to perform an analysis before realizing the mistake.

Comment: What Fillmore calls a "co-operative understander".

Comment: For the specific case of a non-native speaker being understood by native speaker, the term used is *sympathetic interlocutor* (this is what ACTFL uses, for instance). But you're probably looking for the more general term that jlawler pointed out.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a phrase for a phenomenon that makes a native speaker of a certain language hear correct phrases even if the speaker (also native) spoke ambiguously. Or (as I assumed the same term would apply) for a situation where someone is convinced of the intended word despite actual one being written with a typo.